# Setting session variables on button click in web2py

Tags: session-variables, web2py

I have recently started using the MVC architecture and web2py to build an online quiz app. What I am doing right now is that I am redirecting the user to a page that contains buttons to choose the difficulty level of the quiz. What I want to do is as soon as an user clicks on the 'easy button(say)', i want to set a variable session.diff_level as "easy" and go to the easy quiz page. 
     How do I do this ?? Could you please give me the exact syntax ?? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Are you going to have a separate controller function for each type of quiz, or will there be a single controller function for all quiz types, with that function serving different quizzes depending on the type requested (in general, I would assume the latter would make most sense).

Comment: I have a single controller handling all quiz types...basically i am planning to make the controller access the database and return the reuisite fields as a json.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the scaffolding application with Bootstrap, you can create a button link that links to the quiz function and passes the quiz type in the query string. So, in the view file of the page with the buttons, something like:

```
<a href="{{=URL('default', 'quiz', vars=dict(type='easy'))}}" class="btn btn-primary">
  Easy Quiz
</a>
```

Then in the default.py controller:

```
def quiz():
    quiz = get_quiz(type=request.vars.type)
    return dict(quiz=quiz)
```

The quiz.html view would then iterate through the `quiz` object and display the quiz.